# Take high supported picture size in android

Tags: android, image, camera

I have camera app that take picture. My problem is when I take picture it's 240*320 but my camera can take HD picture . how can I take high supported picture whit my camera ? I try this code :

```
public void GetHighResolutionForCamera(){
    int Max = 0;
    Camera.Size MR = null ;
    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> resolution ;
    resolution = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    for (Camera.Size size : resolution) {
        if(Max < size.height){
            MR = size ;
            Max = size.height;
        }
    }
    params.setPictureSize(MR.width, MR.height);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}
```

but I get error when try to set parameters. is this related to surface view ? when I can set parameters to my camera ?

this is logcat:

```
08-21 22:21:27.442: D/AndroidRuntime(27812): Shutting down VM
08-21 22:21:27.442: W/dalvikvm(27812): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a5e700)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mytackpicture/com.example.mytackpicture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at com.example.mytackpicture.MainActivity.GetHighResolutionForCamera(MainActivity.java:63)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at com.example.mytackpicture.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-21 22:21:27.458: E/AndroidRuntime(27812):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What error do you get? Logcat output would be mighty helpful.

Comment: thanks for response . updated

Comment: What's line 63? Is `mCamera` null?

Comment: no mcamera is not null , I use this function after get camera instance and set surface in onCreate

Comment: So what's line 63? According to your logcat, something on that line is null.

Comment: I don't know , there is noting in GetHighResolutionForCamera() to be null

Comment: Yes, there is. It's whatever was on line 63 when you compiled/ran this to get that logcat error. You might not know *why* it's null, but *something* there is null. If you won't point out which line that is, you're not going to get any help.

Comment: yes it's true , I try to figure out , tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solve and it's corrected method :

```
public void GetHighResolutionForCamera(){
    int Max = 0;
    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> resolution ;
    resolution = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Camera.Size MR = resolution.get(0);
    for (Camera.Size size : resolution) {
        if(Max < size.height){
            MR = size ;
            Max = size.height;
        }
    }
    params.setPictureSize(MR.width, MR.height);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}
```

problem because MR was null